# How to suppress stargazer() information (before the actual table) in output file

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, stargazer

I'm trying to create a table with stargazer, but I would like to include only the table and not the output before the table. I'm not sure if I have a formatting issue or an issue with the underlying object.

```
# load packages
library(quantmod)
library(stargazer)
library(forecast)

# Get data from FRED
TXPCPI <- getSymbols(Symbols = "TXPCPI", src = "FRED", auto.assign = FALSE)
# Percentage change in personal income in Texas
gTXPCPI <- 100*(TXPCPI - lag.xts(TXPCPI,1))/lag.xts(TXPCPI,1)
# Training sample subset
training_sample <- index(gTXPCPI["1947/2010"])
# AR(1) and AR(2) processes
ar1 <- arima(gTXPCPI[training_sample], order = c(1,0,0))
ar2 <- arima(gTXPCPI[training_sample], order = c(2,0,0))
# Format to fit inside single table
model_names <- c("AR(1)","AR(2)") 
model <- list()
model$ar1 <- ar1
model$ar2 <- ar2
# Print table
star <- capture.output(stargazer(model, header = FALSE, single.row = TRUE, column.labels = model_names
, dep.var.labels.include = FALSE, report = "vc*", dep.var.caption =
"Texas Per Capita Income Growth", type = "latex"))
star <- sub('^.+\\caption.+$','', star) 
cat(star, sep='\n')
```

The output:

```
Call:
arima(x = gTXPCPI[training_sample], order = c(1, 0, 0))

Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept
      0.5221     5.8438
s.e.  0.1055     0.7663

sigma^2 estimated as 8.876:  log likelihood = -160.84,  aic = 327.68

Training set error measures:
                      ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE
Training set -0.03052831 2.979283 2.235901 -27.58182 94.34842 0.9028272
                   ACF1
Training set -0.1138154

Call:
arima(x = gTXPCPI[training_sample], order = c(2, 0, 0))

Coefficients:
         ar1     ar2  intercept
      0.3762  0.2832     5.7120
s.e.  0.1235  0.1367     1.0182

sigma^2 estimated as 8.3:  log likelihood = -158.78,  aic = 325.56

Training set error measures:
                      ME    RMSE     MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE
Training set -0.04680256 2.88103 2.16846 -23.23882 92.33665 0.8755952
                    ACF1
Training set -0.01369017

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 

  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Texas Per Capita Income Growth} \\ 
\cline{2-3} 
 & AR(1) & AR(2) \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2)\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 ar1 & 0.522$^{***}$ & 0.376$^{***}$ \\ 
  ar2 &  & 0.283$^{**}$ \\ 
  intercept & 5.844$^{***}$ & 5.712$^{***}$ \\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & 64 & 64 \\ 
Log Likelihood & $-$160.839 & $-$158.778 \\ 
$\sigma^{2}$ & 8.876 & 8.300 \\ 
Akaike Inf. Crit. & 327.678 & 325.556 \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

I do not want to include any of the output before \begin{table}[!htbp] \centering. I have never seen this problem before and am clueless as to what is causing it or how to fix it. I can add more details if needed, please let me know if you have problems reproducing the code.

Edit:
Rest of the code

```
# Get data from FRED
TXPCPI <- getSymbols(Symbols = "TXPCPI", src = "FRED", auto.assign = FALSE)
# Percentage change in personal income in Texas
gTXPCPI <- 100*(TXPCPI - lag.xts(TXPCPI,1))/lag.xts(TXPCPI,1)
# Training sample subset
training_sample <- index(gTXPCPI["1947/2010"])
```

Comment: You haven't share the data to make this reproducible but are you sure  you get the output you have shown after doing `cat(star, sep='\n')` ? I ran this on two dummy arima models and it gives exactly what you were hoping for i.e data from `\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering.`

Comment: @Ronak I added the rest of the code to make it reproducible. I haven't had any problems in the past when I use this code on dummy arima models, it's just giving me problems when I use actual data for my arima models.

Comment: Even on your code I get the output starting form `\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering `. There is nothing before that. I'll suggest you restart your R session and try the exact same code again.

Comment: I found the cause of my problem. The `forecast` package interferes with the `stargazer`package for some odd reason. I'm not sure what causes the problem, but not loading the `forecast` package solved the formatting issue.

Comment: Bug report lodged at https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/issues/883